# Wicket - Initialize external Class

Tags: web-applications, wicket

id like to initialize my imported Client.class, which communicates with the backend, in my WicketApplication. I know that I have to do this in my WebApplication.class (in the init method right?). But how can I get this instance in my Page.classes? How can I communicate with it?

Thanks for advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the current Application by using `getApplication()` or `WebApplication.get()`. From there you should be able to narrow its type to your own implementation and call the getter on your `Client.class` attribute. Please keep in mind that Application is a shared object between all you users and your Client attribute has to be thread safe if you don't want nasty things to happen...

Comment: You can also create a static method on your application class that does the casting for you, i.e. `MyApplication.get()` will return `MyApplication` type.

Answer (score 0):

The least tightly coupled way to do so would be by using a Dependency Injection Framework like Google Guice and have the instance injected into your components. Other than that the answer by Cedric Gatay covers the solution pretty good.

Using DI would offer the additional bonus of not having to worry about getting a different implementation in place for unit tests as you could easily define one in your testmodule.

You could stay on middle ground by 'injecting' your external class manually in your page constructors. That would spare you the hassle of including new technology at this point without barring the way of switching to it at a later point. That way your pages wouldn't be tied to a specific (yours) implementation of WebApplication and could be tested easily by supplying a different (mocked) instance of your external class in tests.

Comment: Today I read about this DIs. I am new to wicket and I thought first to try it without Injections. But it's not recommended to work without it, isnt it?

Comment: @user1090145 I'm the wrong person to ask this question since I'm a huge fan of both Wicket and Google Guice. I think, it makes decoupling easier beyond recognition but others argue that it hides important information at unexpected places (like the modules). There is an alternative approach that I included in my answer.